# function not being called | reactjs | axios | redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

I have a function in `src/actions/index.js` which is fetching data from an external api using axios. It uses a dispatch method and sets the payload as the data fetched from the api.

I then import the  function in my src/App.js like so:

`import {fetchPosts}  from "./actions/index.js";`

**fetchPosts** then gets passed as a prop to the **Button** component, along with `configureButton.buttonText` (gets correctly passed), which when clicked should trigger the function to fetch the api; however, it does not run.

```
const App = ({ posts }) => {

  const configureButton = {
    buttonText: "Get Posts",
// this is where the fetchPosts f() gets set as the emitEvent prop
    emitEvent: fetchPosts,
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />

      <section className="main">
//destructure the configureButton object
        <Button {...configureButton} />
  </section>
    </div>
 )
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    posts: state.posts,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(App);
```

Button.js component:

```
const Button = ({ buttonText, emitEvent}) => {
 const submitEvent = () => {
        if(emitEvent){
            emitEvent()
        }
    }
  return (
    <button onClick={submitEvent} data-test="buttonComponent">{buttonText}</button>
  )
}
export default Button
```

Why is the **fetchPosts** function not being called?

Comment: Is the submitEvent function called? Is the fetchPosts function really not called? Try console.log for example in each of those methods, to see how it behaves.

Comment: Your first snippet looks syntacticly wrong, as you missed to add a closing bracket of the return in your App function. Maybe you should add the definition of your fetchPosts function.

Comment: @BrunoPfohl the submitEvent func does work; however , when I try to console.log inside the fetchPosts function it is not triggering

Comment: i was able to narrow it down , and it is the way I dispatch in this fetchPost function as to why it wont work

Comment: Is this a thunk? If so, it needs to be dispatched.